# set request header with protoype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, prototypejs

I want to remake the following jquery code to prototype :

```
jQuery.ajax({ url:url,
          type: 'POST',
          beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
          data: { 'value': value } , 
          success: function(response) {
          }
        });
```

Ii tried this but the request header is missing so how can i set it

```
new Ajax.Request(url , {
    parameters: { 'value': value },
    onSuccess: function(transport) {
    }
  })
```

Comment: Questions regarding refactoring working code should be posted on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchane.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `requestHeaders` option http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/

```
new Ajax.Request(url , {
  parameters: { 'value': value },
  requestHeaders: { 'X-CSRF-Token', ... },
  onSuccess: function(transport) {}
})
```